# Exception from Chrono

Tags: c++, physics

I am new to Project Chrono and try to run the tutorials but got stuck in the first one. Here is the code:

```
#include "chrono/physics/ChLinkMotorRotationSpeed.h"
#include "chrono/physics/ChSystemNSC.h"

using namespace chrono;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    GetLog() << "Copyright (c) 2017 projectchrono.org\nChrono version: " << CHRONO_VERSION << "\n\n";

    {
        //
        // EXAMPLE 1:
        //

        GetLog() << " Example: create a physical system.. \n";

        // The physical system: it contains all physical objects.
        ChSystemNSC sys;

        // Create a bunch of rigid bodies..
        // Note that we use shared pointers, so you don't
        // have to care about the deletion (never use delete.. for
        // objects managed with shared pointers! it will be automatic!)
        auto my_body_A = chrono_types::make_shared<ChBody>();
        auto my_body_B = chrono_types::make_shared<ChBody>();
        auto my_body_C = chrono_types::make_shared<ChBody>();

        // Create some markers..
        // Markers are 'auxiliary coordinate systems' to be added
        // to rigid bodies.
        // Again, note that they are managed by shared pointers.
        auto my_marker_a1 = chrono_types::make_shared<ChMarker>();
        auto my_marker_a2 = chrono_types::make_shared<ChMarker>();
        auto my_marker_b1 = chrono_types::make_shared<ChMarker>();
        auto my_marker_b2 = chrono_types::make_shared<ChMarker>();

        // You can create some forces too...
        auto my_force_a1 = chrono_types::make_shared<ChForce>();
        auto my_force_a2 = chrono_types::make_shared<ChForce>();

        // Here you will add forces and markers to rigid
        // bodies.
        // Note: the same marker shouldn't be added to multiple bodies.
        my_body_A->AddMarker(my_marker_a1);
        my_body_A->AddMarker(my_marker_a2);
        my_body_A->AddForce(my_force_a1);
        my_body_A->AddForce(my_force_a2);
        my_body_B->AddMarker(my_marker_b1);
        my_body_B->AddMarker(my_marker_b2);

        // Ok, remember that rigid bodies must be added to
        // the physical system.
        sys.AddBody(my_body_A);
        sys.AddBody(my_body_B);
        sys.AddBody(my_body_C);

        // Show the hierarchy in the shell window...
        GetLog() << "Here's the system hierarchy which you built: \n\n ";
        sys.ShowHierarchy(GetLog());

        // Do you want to remove items? Use the
        // Remove...() functions.
        my_body_A->RemoveAllForces();

        // Remove a single body..
        sys.RemoveBody(my_body_A);

        // Add markers to another body...
        my_body_B->AddMarker(my_marker_a1);
        my_body_B->AddMarker(my_marker_a2);
        my_body_B->AddForce(my_force_a1);
        my_body_B->AddForce(my_force_a2);

        // By the way, you can set an Ascii name for objects as desired:
        my_marker_a1->SetName("JohnFoo");
        // ..so you can later use  my_body_B.SearchMarker("JohnFoo"); etc.

        GetLog() << "\n\n\nHere's the system hierarchy after modifications: \n\n ";
        sys.ShowHierarchy(GetLog());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I added all the required modules, libraries and dlls to the project so now I don't get error messages  related to them but get an exception which I don't now how to handle. This exception happens just when code finishes and before the 'return 0'. My idea is that the exception happens because the shared pointer is removed twice but I am not sure it is the case.

Here is the exception message that I get in the 'memory' file of visual studio:

*Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF6E0ECA3E (ChronoEngine.dll) in ConsoleApplication7.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000185243FCA0F*

The part of the memory file which throws exception is here:

```
void _Destroy() noexcept override { // destroy managed resource
        delete _Ptr;
    }
```

Comment: @knoxgon: I tried to your fix but it didn't work. It gave exactly same exeption as I got before. Consider that I reach all the way to the end of code before I get this exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the markers are still linked to `my_body_A` after you remove. When you try to add it to `my_body_B`, this linkage is causing the exception.

You should create new markers to add to `my_body_B`:

```
my_body_A->AddMarker(my_marker_a1);
my_body_A->AddMarker(my_marker_a2);
sys.AddBody(my_body_A);
sys.AddBody(my_body_B);
sys.AddBody(my_body_C);

sys.RemoveBody(my_body_A); //Here, you delete it as usual

//And here you create new marker for my_body_B
auto new_marker_a1 = chrono_types::make_shared<ChMarker>();
auto new_marker_a2 = chrono_types::make_shared<ChMarker>();

my_body_B->AddMarker(new_marker_a1);
my_body_B->AddMarker(new_marker_a2);
my_body_B->AddForce(my_force_a1);
my_body_B->AddForce(my_force_a2);
```